# Checkbox is checked but value not passed to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, model-binding

I am developing application in ASP.Net MVC and getting strange problem. In my view I am showing checkbox as On/Off switch like this:

[image] [image]

for this I am using following jquery code

```
function checkSwitch()
{
  $('input.checkSwitch').each(function() {

    if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
        $(this).wrap('<div class="checkSwitch on" />');
    } else {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="checkSwitch off" />');
    }

    $(this).parent('div.checkSwitch').each(function() {
        $(this).append('<div class="checkSwitchInner"><div class="checkSwitchOn">On</div><div class="checkSwitchHandle"></div><div class="checkSwitchOff">Off</div></div>');
    });

  });
}

$(document).on('click', 'div.checkSwitch', function() {

var $this = $(this);

if($this.hasClass('off')){
    $this.addClass('on');
    $this.removeClass('off');
    $this.children('input.checkSwitch').attr('checked', 'checked');
} else if($this.hasClass('on')){
    $this.addClass('off');
    $this.removeClass('on');
    $this.children('input.checkSwitch').removeAttr('checked');
}

});
```

Html code for showing checkbox in view is like this:

```
<script>
   checkSwitch();
</script>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ENABLED, new { @class = "checkSwitch", @checked = "checked" })
```

here ENABLED is boolean field in model like this:

```
public bool ENABLED { get; set; }
```

In browser for this view html code generated is like this:

[image]

Now when I open view, checkbox is displayed as On/Off switch, when I make checkbox which is On(checked) to Off(unchecked) OR Off(unchecked) to On(checked) (ie. click only ONCE) and submit form it post proper values to controller. But when I click more than ONCE to change checkbox status like On(checked) to Off(unchecked) again to On(checked) OR click any number of times and at end make it On(checked) it posts false to controller everytime. I don't know why this is happening. As per jquery code above it's making checkbox checked when it's On(checked). I cross-chekced it's working in FireBug it's added attribute Checked="Checked" when checkbox is checked(On) and removes attribute when it's unchecked(Off). I am not able to find out reason why it's not posting true even checkbox is checked(On) when it's clicked more than ONCE. Please tell me what's wrong in code.

Thanks...

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but your code has the script before the `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`. Is that correct? And in the helper your setting `@checked = "checked"` meaning the initial value is always checked irrespective of the value of property `ENABLED`?

Comment: Actually javascript code line <script> checkSwitch(); </script> is present in head tag of my page I just added it for showing how I used this method to show switch type checkbox. Yes, initially I want my checkbox to checked(On) but user may change it to unchecked(Off) etc..

Comment: Just copied your code to my test project and I can't reproduce your issue. Works correctly every time no matter how many times I click `<div class="checkSwitch" ..>` Note I just added `<style .on {background-color: green;} .off {background-color: red;}</style>`. What I did notice was that clicking on certain parts of the `<div>` did **not** toggle the actual checkbox state despite toggling the classname from `on` to `off` (and vice versa). I suggest you unhide the real checkbox and see it in action as I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: I have confirmed that if you use `prop('checked', true)` instead of `attr('checked', 'checked');` and prop('checked', false)` instead of `removeAttr('checked');` then it should work as expected (PeterKA has just included this in his edit). Note you should also remove `@checked = "checked"` from the helper and instead set the value of property `ENABLED` to `true` in the controller (or in the models default constructor) before you pass the model to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have a hidden `input` field with the same name `ENABLED`, that has a fixed value `false`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ENABLED" value="false"> <!-- THIS IS THE CAUSE -->

<input id="ENABLED" class="CheckSwitch" type="checkbox" value="true" name="ENABLED" checked="checked">
```

It's also advisable to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()`; therefore use

```
$this.children('input.checkSwitch').prop('checked', true);
//instead of $this.children('input.checkSwitch').attr('checked', 'checked'); and

$this.children('input.checkSwitch').prop('checked', false);
//instead of $this.children('input.checkSwitch').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. Actually this hidden field is added by Html.CheckBoxFor helper method to pass value of false when checkbox is Off(unchecked) and when checkbox is On(checked) value of true, false is passed as per this link http://www.mindstorminteractive.com/topics/jquery-fix-asp-net-mvc-checkbox-truefalse-value/. But in my case when checkbox is changed more than ONCE it pass only false which is strange behaviour of checkbox.

Comment: What controls the value of this hidden input?

Comment: This hidden field remains as it is. I am not changing it's value in code.

Comment: Can you at least check it's value in the generated HTML when the wrong value is submitted. Sounds to me that whatever is supposed to change that value is broken.

Comment: Hidden fields value remains same that is False. Just attribute checked="checked" is added to checkbox field when it's On(checked) and removed same when Off(unchecked).

Comment: I could be wrong but I think that's the value that's submitted and it's not changing. Can you update your code per the updated answer and see if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this problem which is more readable and easy to use.

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    var inp = $(this);
    inp.val(inp.prop('checked'));
});
```

This way, every checkbox will have `True` value when is checked and `False` when it's unchecked and also the controller and action is able to understand the state of checkbox.